# Laravel Redirect to Last page number After Editing

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 for developing a web application that having a table of lists and an edit page.

the list page showing 3 recorders per page like this...

```
public function EmployeeList(){
    $data = DB::table('employees')->paginate(3);
    return View::make('admin.tables')
        ->with('data',$data);       
}
```

and the edit page functionality working correctly.

When click on the edit button from page 3 its loads the required data in edit page and after submitting the form in edit page, I ma redirecting to the list page and needs to show the last visited  page (here page.3).

How can I show the page I tried the below codes.

```
return Redirect::back();

return Redirect::to(route('employees'));  // its loading from page 1.
```

How can I solve the issue..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can send the redirect with a parameter for the "page".
Something like route('employees', 3); and detect that when you load the view.

Comment: but how to know the page number in edit action function or page ?

Comment: I'm sure you have access to a parameter like that, I'm not sure if you are doing all the pagination server-side or with ajax calls etc... but you could add a hidden input with the page or you can give us more details about your implementation. You should have it in the route anyway... but depends on your implementation.